# Parameter to ArrayData constructor needs to be an object or associative array

Tags: templates, silverstripe

I have the following `ArrayList` which is iterated in the front end under `$SuitableRooms`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9db25ffe78b14463b7b4392f9da9d7f8

I can navigate the properties of the first dimension with no issue eg.

```
<% loop $SuitableRooms %>
    $Name <!-- returns "Grande Club Room" for example (correct) -->

    <% loop $Top.SuitableRooms.Attributes %> // I know $Top.SuitableRooms isn't needed, just put this here to emphasise that I know I'm in the right scope
        $Name <br/> <!-- should return "Smokers Allowed" for example but returns "Attributes" -->
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

SHOULD return:

> Grande Club Room
>
> - Smokers Allow
> - Ocean View
> - Etc

But returns:

> Grande Club Room
>
> - Attributes
> - Attributes
> - Attributes

So obviously the issue is in the structure of my ArrayList though am unable to find out where I am going wrong.

Comment: In your code are you calling `<% loop $Top.SuitableRooms.Attributes %>` or `<% loop $Attributes %>`?

Comment: In the context provided either is correct and both would work @3dgoo - found my issue and posted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer was very obviously "in my face" within the defintion of "associated array"

```
ArrayData::create(
    array(
        array(
            "Im not accessible"
        )
    )
)
```

*versus*

```
ArrayData::create(
    array(
        "Items" => array(
            "I am now accessible"
        )
    )
)
```